# Laptop fan stops working whenever I move the laptop

Tags: laptop, fan

Ok so I'm not sure if this question exactly belongs here but I guess it does causes it's hardware related.
So my laptop fan runs normally whenever it is idle, but whenever I move it, the fans stops functioning normally.

It runs only on full speed and doesn't return it's speed. So if I try to see the speed of the fan it returns 0 but the fan meanwhile runs on full speed. Like after a certain temperature it would run on full speed and then stop. It's either full speed or nothing.

And it resolves on it's own after the laptop is idle for a while. It returns it's speed if I ask for it.

Would appreciate if anyone knows why this occurs or if there is anyway to actually resolve this completely.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what is happening. You speak of moving the laptop, and when it reaches a certain temperature, the fan starts roaring. The temperature part and spinning down adter cooled, that sounds like normal behaviour. But the moving part is a bit vague. Could you elaborate please.

Comment: Like picking up the laptop from the desk and taking it somewhere else and putting it there, or like putting it in a bag and going somewhere. The temperature and cooling part isn't normal because the fan doesn't show it's speed in speedfan. It just returns a 0. And the fan also runs ONLY at full speed.

Comment: Hvae you checked your fan speed/curve in the BIOS?

Comment: Speedfan doesn't have to show a speed at all, that is all dependent on your system. If you have a fan that is either on or off, I would also expect speedfan to show nothing.

Comment: No but here's the thing. Normally the speedfan DOES show the speed.